# How to move to different screen in bottom tab drawer without registering it in tab drawer navigation in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I am creating a React Native app where I am using bottom tab drawer like in the attached image. In this app here I have only four screens registered and I have multiple screens for say 30 or 40 and I cannot register them all in bottom tab drawer so I want only four screens and inside each screen I want multiple screens .

Now let's start with **profile screen** and in my profile screen I gave a button register that will move me to register Screen but when I click on that it says

```
The action 'JUMP_TO' with payload {"name":"RegisterScreen"} was not handled by any navigator.

Do you have a screen named 'RegisterScreen'?

If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator.
```

How can I open register screen inside **profile tab**?

My code of bottom tabs:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow strict-local
 */

import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  useColorScheme,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import HomeScreen from './Screens/HomeScreen';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from "@react-navigation/native-stack"

import SettingsScreen from './Screens/SettingsScreen';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import OrderScreen from './Screens/OrderScreen';
import ProfileScreen from './Screens/ProfileScreen';
import RegisterScreen from "./Screens/RegisterScreen"
import LoginScreen from './Screens/LoginScreen';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const App= () => {

  return (
    <View style={styles.body}>
      <NavigationContainer>
    
        <Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName='MyApp'
        screenOptions={{
          tabBarActiveTintColor:"#E0FFFF",
          tabBarActiveBackgroundColor:"#20B2AA"
        }}
        >
            <Tab.Screen 
            name="Home" 
            
            component={HomeScreen}
            options={{
              tabBarLabel:"Home",
              tabBarIcon:({color,size})=>(
                <MaterialCommunityIcons name='home' color={"black"} size={30}/>
              )
            }}
            
            />
            
            <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Order" component={OrderScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen}/>

          </Tab.Navigator>

          
      </NavigationContainer>

    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  body:{
    flex:1,
    backgroundColor:"#fff"
  }

});

export default App;
```

This is my profile screen code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Pressable, ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import LoginScreen from './LoginScreen'
import RegisterScreen from './RegisterScreen'
import {NavigationContainer, useNavigation} from "@react-navigation/native"

const ProfileScreen = ({navigation}) => {
    // const navigation = useNavigation();
    return (
        <ScrollView>

            <View style={styles.body}>

                <View style={styles.tile}>
                    <View>
                        <Text style={{textAlign:"center",fontSize:20,fontWeight:"bold",color:"#000"}}>Your Accout</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View>
                        <Pressable
                            style={({pressd})=>[
                            {backgroundColor:pressd
                                ? 'rgb(210,230,255)':
                                    "red"
                            
                            },{ margin:10}
                        ]}
                        onPress={()=>{
                          navigation.jumpTo("RegisterScreen")
                        }}
                        >
                            <Text style={styles.registerButton}>Register</Text>

                        </Pressable>
                    </View>


                </View>

                <View style={styles.tile}>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.tile}>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.tile}>
                </View>

            </View>
            
                    
        </ScrollView>
    )
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    body:{
        flex:1,
        
    },
    tile:{
        margin:5,
        backgroundColor:"red",
        borderRadius:10,
        height:200,
    
    },
    register:{
        justifyContent:"center"
    },
    registerButton:{
        padding:15,
        textAlign:"center",
        width:100,
        height:50,
        borderRadius:10,
        backgroundColor:"green",
        fontWeight:"bold",
        color:"black",
    }

})

export default ProfileScreen
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, your profile tab must be a navigator by itself with initial screen being Profile screen, find below the code for the same,

```js
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const ProfileRoutes = () => {
return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
    <Stack.Navigator />
}
```

Whilst defining tab route change the code like below,

```
<Tab.Screen name="ProfileStack" component={ProfileRoutes}/>
```

In the on click,

```
navigation.navigate('Register');
```

Comment: it is not working. in profile tab which is a component it has button named Register and on clicking on that button i want to go to register screen

Comment: Did u change the profile tab as mentioned?

Comment: I did everything you wrote above

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Or please recreate the app in codesandbox and share the link

Comment: The action 'JUMP_TO' with payload {"name":"RegisterScreen"} was not handled by any navigator.

Do you have a screen named 'RegisterScreen'?

If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator.

this is the error..it means i need to register my resgister screen into tab drawer which i dont want

Comment: you have not changed the code while button click as mentioned in the answer, its still calling, also you have to create a component by the name RegisterScreen..  you are mixing up things, if you gimme a sample code on codesanbox I can help you.

Comment: alright it is workig, i dont know how,,, but it is working,,i used your code,and it is this is strange,,,anyhow thank you so much for your help...but now i am getting two status bars, one for in one screen, one for profile stack and one for stack navigator, how do i hide them? or display only one

Comment: you can follow this documentation...https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator#headershown

Answer (score 1):

navigation.jumpTo() only works for bottom tab screens. try navigation.navigate()

Comment: i cannot navigate as my screen is not registered into Tab.Screen and if i follow above method it says do you have screenname registerScreen

Comment: You should put "Register" as parameter not registerScreen

Comment: Yeah i solved it now...but thanks for help